# VBA to insert data in Search box IE

Tags: excel, vba

When i insert Few words in searchbox, Its fetching related data.
I need to select first option from it.

There is one website "https://indiarailinfo.com/"
When i search "ADI" in from station box, system fetching related station having  "ADI" in their name?. First option always showing very close match to it.
How can i select First Option from it using vba code

```
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate "https://indiarailinfo.com/"
While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
ie.Visible = True
ie.document.querySelector("[placeholder='from station']").Value = "ADI"
```

HTML Codes can be available from that site

It's Bring First Answer in Dropdown like "ADI/Ahmedabad Junction"
How can i get this answer in selected"

Kindly Suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automation purists won't like using javascript to execute but I will use here for IE to trigger dropdown. If I was going pure route I would use selenium.

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub MakeSelection()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, t As Date, dropdown1 As Object
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://indiarailinfo.com/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document.querySelector("[placeholder='from station']")
            .Focus
            .Value = "ADI"
            ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('[placeholder^=from]').click();"
        End With
        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set dropdown1 = .document.querySelectorAll(".icol span")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While dropdown1.Length = 0
        If dropdown1.Length > 0 Then
            dropdown1.item(0).Click
        End If

        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

For automation purists using selenium basic

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub MakeSelection()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const Url = "https://indiarailinfo.com/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get Url
        .FindElementByCss("[placeholder='from station']").SendKeys "ADI"
        .FindElementByCss(".icol span").Click
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: IE example doesn't work with "from station" and "to station" together. If  took "from station" then "to station" doesn't work. Many Many Thanks to you QHarr for your anytime support.

Comment: I have tried too much. "From Station" and " To Station" doesn't work together.

Comment: Do you want me to try and write something for both?